# Ubuntu 16.04 cpu overheating

Tags: cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

Hello dear Ubuntu users!

I have recently got back to Ubuntu system and made a dual installation with Windows 10. However, I experience a severe CPU overheating problem, let me explain in details.
First I could not even install Ubuntu because laptop (Acer Aspire V3-571G) shut down during the installation but I managed to install. 
In fact, I can not really use the system because even when I do nothing (just boot and wait) CPU temperature goes up). I was searching everywhere but in fact nothing really helped. Myt I launched Firefox and sensors show 77 degrees Celcium. 
There are no such problems in Windows10

Looking forward to any advices.
Regards,
Alex